# Css gallery images overlap cause the browser width is limited

Tags: javascript, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONzC0.gif)code for image gallery on adding any more images the images overlap cause the browser width is limited; according to mozilla developer tools the browser width is 1247 and height is 300

How is it possible to add more images

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Computer Science</title>        
</head>
<style>
    .yndr
    {
        float:left;
        animation:droyd 10s infinite;
    }
    .yndroid
    {
        width: calc(500px * 3);            
    }
    .yndroidr
    {
        width: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 150px auto;
        height:300px;
    }

    @keyframes droyd
    {
        10%
        {                
         transform: translateX(-420px);             
        }            
        20%
        {                
         transform: translateX(-840px);             
        }
        30%
        {                
         transform: translateX(-1260px);             
        }            
        40%
        {                
         transform: translateX(-840px);             
        }            
    }
</style>         
<body>
   <div class="yndroidr">
       <div class="yndroid">
           <div class=yndr><img src="iron.gif" width="400" height="200" alt="cy"/></div>               
           <div class=yndr><img src="airconditioner.gif" width="400" height="200" alt="cy"/></div>               
           <div class=yndr><img src="geyser.gif" width="400" height="200" alt="cy"/></div>               
           <div class=yndr><img src="battery.gif" width="400" height="200" alt="cy"/></div>               
       </div>
   </div>         
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added more images, is this what you called *overlap*, I see it works normally.

Check this out:

```css
.yndr
{
    float:left;
    animation:droyd 10s infinite;
}
.yndroid
{
    width: calc(500px * 3);            
}
.yndroidr
{
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 150px auto;
    height:300px;
}

@keyframes droyd
{
    10%
    {                
     transform: translateX(-420px);             
    }            
    20%
    {                
     transform: translateX(-840px);             
    }
    30%
    {                
     transform: translateX(-1260px);             
    }            
    40%
    {                
     transform: translateX(-840px);             
    }            
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="yndroidr">
    <div class="yndroid">
      <div class="yndr"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="cy" /></div>
      <div class="yndr"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/151" alt="cy" /></div>
      <div class="yndr"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/152" alt="cy" /></div>
      <div class="yndr"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/153" alt="cy" /></div>
      <div class="yndr"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/154" alt="cy" /></div>
      <div class="yndr"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/155" alt="cy" /></div>
      <div class="yndr"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/156" alt="cy" /></div>
      <div class="yndr"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/157" alt="cy" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thancs for that would try tomorrow

Comment: its been a busy festive season now at work again; yeah yours does look good let me check what has happened with mine before i get back to you; thancs and happy new year